# OWIN self hosted doesn't receive connections from outside

Tags: asp.net, owin

I have a project which is made of a console application which listens to a port and acts when a message is received.

The messages are received from an asp.net web api based web site.

Both work properly together.

I wanted to combine both solutions into one executable file.
To accomplish that I used OWIN self hosted solution.

I managed to merge the web site into the console application and when working from my local machine I manage to see the web site and everything works well.

The problem occurs when I try to open the website from another machine\device connected to my LAN.

I get no response. I know it is not a firewall issue since my OWIN self hosted using the standalone website's port (I put the website down to make the port available).

This problem didn't occur when both solution where seperate.
I assume it is an owin configuration issue.

I tried to use the following code but I get access denied exception.

```
    options.Urls.Add($"http://{Dns.GetHostName()}:{port}");
    options.Urls.Add($"http://localhost:{port}");
```

If I use only

```
    options.Urls.Add($"http://localhost:{port}");
```

There is no exception and it works from my computer as expected but not from another machine.

I did some search but didn't manage to make it work.
Any kind of assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can either use specific ip-address or use `*` to listen on a port

I use below code for specific ip-address

```
            var ip = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            var ipaddress = ip.AddressList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            options.Urls.Add($"http://{ipaddress}:{port}");
```

or you can also do

```
         options.Urls.Add($"http://*:{port}");
```

Comment: The binding to an ip address didn't work. I got access denied. I'll try the * solution later this day. thanks.

Comment: Try it with port 80, I think you are using different port. You might need : netsh urlacl

Comment: this didn't work as well. the problem was I ran VS as usual and not as an administrator. Once I did all worked well

Comment: if you run on port 80, you dont need admin access, or if you want to use other port without admin access, you will have to do `urlacl`

Answer (score 0):

Open the ports on the firewall and

instead to use it

```
WebApp.Start("http://localhost:8080/");
```

Use it:

```
WebApp.Start("http://*:8080/");
```